# How to convert Extended Event action mdmget_TimeStampUTC to datetime?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

SQL Server Extended Events can include an action of mdmtargetpkg.mdmget_TimeStampUTC. It returns a value such as 132085458320550473. How can that be converted to an actual date?

It doesn't appear to be a valid unix timestamp, even using microseconds.

Maybe it's the [TimeStamp is actually RowVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119407/2266979) issue-- but this explicitly has "UTC" in it, implying it's a real time.

`@@VERSION`:

```
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 
    Jul  3 2019 10:02:53 
    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
```

Comment: I don't know what `mdmtargetpkg` is. Could you show the definition of that extended events session? Also, this has nothing to do with `timestamp`/`rowversion`.

Answer (score 1):

The value 132085458320550473 is the number of ticks since January 1, 1601. Use the below function to convert it to datetime:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertTicksToDateTime ( @Ticks bigint )
  RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DateTime datetime2 = '16010101';
    SET @DateTime = DATEADD( DAY, @Ticks / 864000000000, @DateTime );
    SET @DateTime = DATEADD( SECOND, ( @Ticks % 864000000000) / 10000000, @DateTime );
    RETURN DATEADD( NANOSECOND, ( @Ticks % 10000000 ) * 100, @DateTime );
END
```